# Web site layout that changes with different widths?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Does anyone know how to accomplish a different layout based on the browser width, like these two sites?

http://sasquatchfestival.com/

http://css-tricks.com/

I've tried to Google it, look through Stackoverflow questions, and look at their code but I think I am missing something. It actually rearranges and resizes some elements based on the width of the window, but how? Javascript?

Sorry if my search skills are just failing, but I'm not really sure what to look up, the "similar questions" here don't seem related, and even CSS-Tricks doesn't have the info in an easy to find place.

Comment: You can use javascript and/or media queries for the task.

Comment: Look into responsive web design

Comment: Media queries, thats what its called! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use JS to detect browser width. You can simply use CSS media queries to alter the layout.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    ... selector(s) here ...
}
```

Will apply CSS only to screens that are at most 1280px wide.

See also:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/mediaqueries

Comment: I'm making a site and I *just* started to use media queries, but it doesn't look like this changes dynamically after the page has loaded. Is it supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS3 media queries to deliver different styles based on the screen width.  See here for more info:  http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/

If you look at the CSS source of the sasquatchfestival.com site, for example, you can see what they're doing:  http://sasquatchfestival.com/css/screen.css?v=1328828795.  Search for "@media only screen" and you'll see they're delivering different CSS for widths below 768px, between 768-1024px, and above 1024px.

Answer (score 1):

You can reinvent the wheel or merely build/rebuild your web site using one of the many responsive frameworks that are available. I have used both 'Skeleton' and 'Bootstrap by Twitter' Their frameworks can be found at...
Skeleton... [http://www.getskeleton.com/][1]
Bootstrap... [http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/][2]

I have built sites using each... 
Skeleton...  [http://72t.net][3]
Bootstrap... [http://ReactiveWebDesign.net][4]

I'm still trying to decide which I prefer, but right now boot strap seems to offer more features.

Answer (score 0):

May be a little bit of [jMasonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in there, but it also looks a little like what [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) provides in rails, it might be worth pouring over their static CSS version for answers.